# How to run multiple testcases in verilog?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I have written my testcases in "tc1.v" and "tc2.v". The test cases are in the form of tasks. for example:

```
//tc1.v

task tc1(input reg [31:0] j,input reg Reset,output reg dataValidIn);

 //logic
endtask

//tc2.v

task tc2(input reg [31:0] counter,input reg Reset,output reg dataValidIn);

//logic

endtask


module top_test;

  //inputs and outputs
  //logic

   `ifdef testcase1
      `include "tc1.v";
   `else 
     `include "tc2.v"
   `endif


endmodule
```

Problem is I want to run the testcases for every posedge clock. If I include the 'ifdef part in always block, modelsim throws an error. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code above, all the `include is including is the task declaration, not the actual task call. Somewhere else in your code, you must have something like `tc1(x, y, z);` being called in an `initial` or `always` block. Also, to make this more expandable, I recommend not conditionally including the task declarations and leaving it up to the call to determine which task to run. Thus, you can simply add the needed code at the task call rather than the task inclusion:

```
// Have a macro for your test case, you can also declare this in the commandline
`define TESTCASE 1

module top_test;
  ...
  `include "tc1.v"
  `include "tc2.v"
  ...
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    // Switch on the test case to determine which to use
    // NOTE THAT IF THE TASK TAKES LONGER THAN 1 CLOCK CYCLE TO COMPLETE, THIS WILL NOT WORK FOR A TASK PER CLOCK
    case (`TESTCASE)
     1: tc1(...);
     2: tc2(...);
     default: begin
       $display("ERROR: Bad Testcase supplied %d", `TESTCASE);
       $finish;
     end
   endcase
 end
 ...
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks Unn :) You are a savior all the time! If I use the `define macro, modelsim says TESTCASE is not defined. So, I have defined it as a parameter instead and it worked.

Comment: Youre right, I made a bunch of typos; they are fixed now in case you want to use a macro (macros are easier to define on the commandline). But a parameter is another good option :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which I use is to use a runtime switch to specify the testcase to the simulator. This saves you from having to recompile your test/design for each test and you can batch run all your tests without having to recompile.

Verilog has a system call `$value$plusargs (string, variable)` that can extract any variable from simulator arguments. You can use that to extract the test name, and use the `if` or `case` statement to select between the different sources like in the above answers.

You can launch the simulator like this `<simulator> +TESTNAME=tc1`

In your testbench code you would extract the TESTNAME argument

```
if ($value$plusargs("TESTNAME=%s", testname)) begin
  $display("Running test %0s.", testname);
  if (testname == "tc1")
    `include "tc1.v"
  else if (testname == "tc2)
    `include "tc2.v"
end
```